# Javascript script not loading at all

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a game in HTML5 using the canvas and I have this code using EaselJS.

http://pastebin.com/bhKajqgU

"game.js" has an init function but in console it says it is not defined and createjs is not defined either. Basically the scripts aren't loading.

Answer (score 3):

its because you linked it incorrect!

its `<script src=` and NOT `<script scr=`

Comment: It's short for source, not script.